# G forces on Mars Science Laboratory during parachute deployment?

Tags: curiosity, parachute, g-force

The parachute for the MSL was "[designed to survive deployment at Mach 2.2 in the Martian atmosphere, where it will generate up to 65,000 pounds of drag force](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/msl/multimedia/gallery/pia14836.html)."

What was the G force the MSL experienced when the parachute was deployed?

Comment: Your link was broken; I editted it to point to something with the same text, but check that it is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Science_Laboratory) on MSL lists the lander mass as 899 kg and the entry system mass as 2401 kg, for a total mass just before entry of 3300 kg. Before parachute deployment several tungsten balance masses with a total mass of 300 kg were ejected (150 kg before entry and 150 kg after primary deceleration and heating were past), decreasing the mass to 3000 kg. A small mass of heat shield thermal protection system (TPS) material ablated during the heat pulse, but that is very small compared to the system mass.

[This abstract](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/1.A32816) gives the parachute's peak decelerating force as 153,800 Newtons. Acting on a 3000 kg mass, this produces an acceleration magnitude (actually, *deceleration*) of 51.27 m/s^2 or 5.23 gees. It was probably slightly higher than this due to the ablative mass loss, but given the large quasi-random variations in the force provided by the parachute the difference would be in the noise.